# Animate multiple lists collapsing into one

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-animate, transition

I have multiple lists on a page. The number of lists that could exist is arbitrary, but would likely be limited to 10.

There are two views of this page:

- **Mode 1:** All items are categorized and listed in separate lanes.
- **Mode 2:** All items are collapsed into a single list.

A user should be able to toggle between the two modes. I have this [roughly] working - they are collapsed into a single list, but they lose their styling from their parent/origin list.

Ideally, I'd love the transition between the two modes to be animated; that is, when the user clicks the mode toggle button, all of the list items from each lane animate/collapse into a single, alphabetized list. Once in **Mode 2** (single list mode), clicking the toggle again would, ideally, animate the list items back into their original lists.

[**Here's a Fiddle I've been working on.**](http://jsfiddle.net/0gykj381/3/)

In my code, I have four lists, with a hidden `<ul>` that the items can collapse into. I'm having trouble figuring out how and where the animation goes.

```
$(function() {
    $("button").on("click", function() {
        if($(this).text() == "Mode 1") {
            $("#list").show();
            $("li").remove().clone().appendTo("#list");
            $("ul:not(#list)").hide();
            $("button").text("Mode 2");
        }
    });
});
```

---

```
<button>Mode 1</button>

// The hidden list
<ul id="list"></ul>

<ul id="red">
    <li>A</li>
    ...
</ul>
<ul id="blue">
    <li>K</li>
    ...
</ul>
<ul id="gray">
    <li>U</li>
    ...
</ul>
<ul id="green">
    <li>AA</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

**EDIT:** I guess I should specify the animation I'm aiming for. I'd like each individual list item to "fly" from its origin position into the single, collapsed list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright Jon, for Each piece to animate from it's current position to a new position, you have get each element's offset, make them `position:absolute;` then animate them to the correct place.

[In-progress fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/0gykj381/17/)

Here's the jQuery to accompany it.  this also keeps your HTML layout the same:

```
$(function() {
$("button").on("click", function() {
    if($(this).text() == "Mode 1") {
        var elem = $('ul:not(#list) > li'),
            elemH = elem.first().outerHeight(),
            list1Last = {x:$('#red > li:last-of-type').offset().left,
                         y:$('#red > li:last-of-type').offset().top},
            oElem = {x:0, y:0, w:0, h:0}
        $('ul:not(#red)').each(function(e){
            $(this).find('li').each(function(i){
                oElem = {x:$(this).offset().left,
                         y:$(this).offset().top,
                         w:$('#red').width(),
                         h:$(this).outerHeight()}
                console.log(oElem.x, oElem.y);
                $(this).css({"position":"absolute", 
                             "top":oElem.y+(oElem.h*i)+"px",
                             "left":oElem.x+"px",
                             "width":oElem.w+"px"});
                $(this).delay(200*i).animate({"top":(list1Last.y+elemH)*e+(i*elemH)+"px",
                                              "left":list1Last.x+"px"}, 200);
            });
        })
    } else {

    }
});
});
```

What this does is it gets each elements current position using `offset()`, then I change the CSS to make them `position:absolute;` and give them a `left` and `top` value.  This seamlessly makes them absolutely positioned without any bumping.  Then right away, I animate them to their new spot, almost like they're flying as you say. There's ways to get them to fly one by one, but that will require a bit more editing.

Comment: This works, but the animation I was picturing literally treats each list item like a piece of paper that glides from it's origin position into the single list. Is there a way to modify what you've provided?

Comment: @ntgCleaner Are the `ul`'s being appended twice to the displayed list at jsfiddle ?

Comment: Tried clicking "Mode" button more than twice ?